# Install Drupal into a different directory than drupal-vm is installed

Tags: virtual-machine

I installed Drupal Virtual Machine (Drupal VM) from drupalvm.com using vagrant. This worked fine - but I want to install the drupal files into a different directory.

How can I modify the Vagrantfile in order to install drupal and the drupal vm into different directorys (drupal not as a sub diretory of drupal vm). Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the default configured webroot directories by altering the `local_path` property in the `vagrant_synced_folders` array with a custom **config.yml** file (copy over **default.config.yml** if you don't have one).

Per [default.config.yml](https://github.com/geerlingguy/drupal-vm/blob/master/default.config.yml):

```
# A list of synced folders, with the keys 'local_path', 'destination', and
# a 'type' of [nfs|rsync|smb] (leave empty for slow native shares). See
# http://docs.drupalvm.com/en/latest/extras/syncing-folders/ for more info.
vagrant_synced_folders:
  # The first synced folder will be used for the default Drupal installation, if
  # any of the build_* settings are 'true'. By default the folder is set to
  # the drupal-vm folder.
  - local_path: .
    destination: /var/www/drupalvm
    type: nfs
    create: true
```

Comment: Thank you. If I have already installed with default values and later want to change the drupal directory, is this possible?  Above the synced folder is the whole drupalvm folder which contains the drupal installation (druvalvm/drupal). I want to move/relocate the drupal installation to an folder outside of the drupalvm folder. How?

Comment: Yes you can change the values later and run "vagrant provision" command.The new config takes the place.